# Modifying an ng-repeat model in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

If you have a directive that contains an ng-repeat and you want to modify the model of the ng-repeat how do you do that without creating two separate ng-repeats in the template?  I would like to be able to pass in the model of the ng-repeat as a directive attribute.  So in the case of the string array it would just be something like repeat-model="row" and in the case of the object array it would be repeat-model="row.title".  Is there any way to achieve this?

```js
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module("app")
.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.sampleData = ["sample 1", "sample 2", "sample 3"];
  $scope.sampleData2 = [{title:"sample 1"}, {title:"sample 2"}, {title:"sample 3"}];
})

angular.module("app")
.directive("repeatDirective", function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        template: "<div ng-repeat='row in data'>{{row}}</div>",
        link: function (scope) {}
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <repeat-directive data="sampleData"></repeat-directive>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass an additional attribute to your directive, describing the property you wish to check. I do something similar in a directive I use:

```
<repeat-directive data="sampleData2" property="title"></repeat-directive>
<repeat-directive data="sampleData"></repeat-directive>
```

And then in your directive:

```
.directive("repeatDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            property: '@?'
        },
        template: "<div ng-repeat='row in data'>{{row | repeatDirectiveDisplay:property:useProperty}}</div>",
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.useProperty = !angular.isUndefined(scope.property) && scope.property != null;
        }
    }
})
```

Then you have a new filter called `repeatDirectiveDisplay` like:

```
app.filter('repeatDirectiveDisplay', function() {
    return function(item, property, useProperty) {
        if (useProperty)
            return item[property];
        return item;
    }
});
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OeSZ4zmrvKJEJwhwdO11?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for putting in the extra effort to be as concise as possible.  The first version of your answer was also correct, but this version is written better.